# Ĉu homo povas esti “komforta”?

Tags: word-meaning

En la angla estus normale demandi al homo ĉu ri estas *comfortable*, kaj tio signifus ekzemple ke ri havas komfortan sidlokon. Ankaŭ seĝo povas esti *comfortable*, kaj tio signifas ke ĝi havigas komforton al la sidanto. Ĉu la esperanta vorto *komforta* sekvas la saman modelon, au ĉu ĝi havas nur la duan signifon? Se homo estas *komforta*, ĉu tio signifas ke se oni sidas sur ri oni trovus komforton?

Mi trovas en PIV la jenan difinon:

> **komforta** (io) Provizita je komforto, haviganta komforton: *komforta domo, seĝo, vagono; komfortaj vivcirkonstancoj; konservi komfortan trankvilecon*

La “provizita je komforto” pensigas min ke ĝi povus havi la unuan signifon ĉar *comfortable* homo estus provizita je komforto. Tamen, la difino komenciĝas per “(io)” kaj neniu el la ekzemploj rilatas al homo.

Esplorante la temon mi trovis multe da ekzemploj en la Tekstaro, do eble mi jam respondis al mia demando.

- Kompatinda Klem, John Merchant., 1931

  > mi estus pli *komforta* se mi nur havus sufiĉe por miaj bezonoj
- Kredu min, sinjorino!, Cezaro Rossetti, 1949

  > Ŝi gvidis min al mia ĉambro, diris kelkajn afablajn vortojn, esprimante la esperon ke mi estos komforta

  > Nu, ĉu vere vi estas tute komforta?
- Retoriko, Ivo Lapenna, 1950

  > Multnombra publiko ne povas esti komforta en malgranda salono.
- La ŝtona urbo, Löwenstein, 1999

  > Se li estis persone komforta, li absolute ne rimarkis sian ĉirkaŭaĵon.
- Kontakto 2011-2019, diversaj personoj, 2011-2019

  > mi sentis min tre komforta dum la naĝado

  > Ĉu vi sentas vin komforta en la nuna epoko

Ĉu tiuj ekzemploj estas bonaj?

Se ne, ĉu estas alia maniero esprimi ke homo estas “komforta”?

Answer (score 2):

Se oni rigardas [*komfortigi*](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1g.html#komfor.0igi) en ReVo:

> Havigi komforton al iu:
>
> - sin komfortigi en sia seĝo;
> - en portebla fajrujo brulis amaseto da lignokarbo, plenigante la ĉambron per komfortiga ardo [1](https://reta-vortaro.de/revo/dlg/index-1g.html#komfor.0igi);
> - ŝi venis por plikomfortigi la malfeliĉan beston.

Ankaŭ ekzistas *komfortiĝi* kaj *komfortigi*.

La radiko estas substantiveca, *komforto*:

> [ReVo] Ĉio, kio igas la vivadon pli facila, la loĝadon pli oportuna, la hejmon pli ripoziga; ĉio, kio malpliigas penon kaj laciĝon en la ĉiutaga vivo:

Proksima sinonimo *prizorgiteco*/*proviziteco*. *comfortable* [en] = *prizorgita*.

Laŭ la difino do devus esti *komfortigita*. Tamen certe la ekzemploj de verba uzo pravigas la uzon de ***komforta*** kiel *komforthava*. Do mi dubas la difinon; oni eĉ povus imagi alian bazon de *komfort'*.

La artifiko en Revo por *komforta*:

- komforte sidi;
- senti sin komforte;
- ĉu estas komforte al vi?.

Do oficiale eraroj, devus uzi adverba formo.

> Estus pli komforte al mi ...

Answer (score 2):

Kiel vi mem konstatis, laŭ la difino de "komforta" en PIV la vorto aliĝas al io, kio provizas komforton, ekz. "komforta seĝo".

En la angla demando "Are you comfortable?" "you" estas la ricevanto de ago, kiu provizas, donas komforton. Estas konate, ke la angla forlasas vortojn kaj malhavas rolmontrilojn, dume Esperanto postulas pli eksplicitan markadon, por ke ĝi estu pli vaste komprenata.

Mi povas imagi minimume alternativojn

- Ĉu vi sidas komforte?
- Ĉu estas komforte al vi?

el kiuj la unua sonas al mi pli natura.

Se vi parolas pri homoj, kiuj "provizas komforton", miakrede la ĝusta vorto estas "[agrabla](https://vortaro.net/#agrabla_kd)".

Answer (score 1):

> Ĉu tiuj ekzemploj estas bonaj?

Ne, ili estas eraraj. Anstataŭ `komforta` vi povus pensi pri `oportuna` (ŝuo, vestaĵo) por eble vidi/senti pli klare kial tiuj frazoj malĝustas.

> Se ne, ĉu estas alia maniero esprimi ke homo estas “komforta”?

Jes, ekzemple:

```
Mi sentas komforton.
```

Kaj se vi volas demandi tion:

```
Ĉu vi sentas komforton?
```

Ĉar komforton oni povas [ĝui, senti, voli, ...](https://tekstaro.com/?s=610f14cc22731)